# How to cache json data with Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I know how to cache it, but how do I retrieve it later. The documentation (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/features/cache.html) only gives an example using an image, which to retrieve all you need to do is get the url.

```
var showCachedLogo = function (file) {
  forge.file.URL(file, function (url) {
    var logo = document.createElement('img');
    logo.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(logo);
  });
}
```

How would I do the same, except with json data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forge.file.string` to get the contents of a saved file as a string. You should be able to use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON data from that.

see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html#string

e.g.

```
var getJsonData = function (file) {
    forge.file.string(file, function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        forge.logging.log(parsed);
    });
}
```